# autocomplete can't wait until JSON from server loaded

Tags: jquery, jquery-autocomplete

As I mentioned on the subject, server loaded approx in 200-1000 ms (from debug log), but I must press one more key to make it shows the results. even I make autocomplete delay longer, it still can't show the results, I still must press a key.

```
var timer;
//to wait for x ms until some chars typed
$("#keyword").bind("keyup", function(e) {
    if ($(this).val().length > 2)
    {
        window.clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = window.setTimeout(function(){               
            var datax = "";
            $(function () {
                $.getJSON("URI", ({"search":$("#keyword").val()}),function(datax){  
                    $("#keyword").autocomplete({
                        minLength: 3,
                        delay: 2000,
                        source: datax,
                        focus: function(event,ui){
                            $("#keyword").val( ui.item.nama);
                            return false;
                        },
                        select: function(event,ui){
                            $("#keyword").val( ui.item.nama);
                            $("#btnCariMainHeader").click();
                            return false;
                        }
                    })
                    .data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function(ul,item){
                            return $("<li>")
                            .data( "item.autocomplete",item)
                            .append("<a><table width='100%'><tr><td width='60px'>"+"<img height='60px' src='/thumb/" + item.value + ".jpg'/>"+"</td><td><b>"+item.nama+"</b><br><span class='suffix'>"+item.value+" "+item.bu+"</span><br><span class='suffix'>"+item.pos+"</span></td></tr></table></a>")
                            .appendTo(ul);
                    };
                });
            });
         },2000); 
    }
});
```

Comment: You do realize that the autocomplete widget supports loading data from the server, either by using a standard JSON format or a custom callback function, right? You don't need to do any of this kludginess.

Comment: @Matti thank you for your explanation, 
i just started learning this powerful tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code you are creating a jQuery autocomplete after getting the JSON results.

But note that jQuery autocomplete doesn't need all these complex code written. You can directly use a remote datasource (in JSON format) as an input to the autocomplete. Also there is no need to bind keyup event for showing the suggestions, this will be automatically  be done by the plugin.

```
$("#birds").autocomplete({
    source: "search.php", // This is the url that returns the JSON list
    minLength: 2,
    select: function(event, ui) {
        log(ui.item ? "Selected: " + ui.item.value + " aka " + ui.item.id : "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value);
    } });
```

You can find the complete [documentation and sample here](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote).

Comment: Thank You Sir... its very simple and works...
i'm just started learning this powerful tools since stuck so long with traditional-coding.